# Login using Azure from a Capacitor built app opens a new login window outside the app

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am using capacitor 3.0 to build a native iOS app with React.
The app's user is expected to login first.

I want the user's login to be handled by Microsoft Azure ActiveDirectory B2C and followed this tutorial to set this up:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react

Furthermore, Microsoft offers a Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL, https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/login-user.md), which for a login redirects to a screen managed by microsoftonline.com to take the username and password. This is a standard login interface by Microsoft, which can be custom-branded but I have not made that change. Just using the standard MS UI.

This redirect works fine in a Web/desktop browser as it opens the Microsoft login screen within the same page without opening a new browser window.

However, when accessing the login from within the Capacitor built iOS app, the user is taken to an external browser for the login, which breaks the user experience.
Any ideas on why capacitor launches a browser for login when this is not the case with the regular React web browser (non-Capacitor)?